# pandas custom merge with condition key1 contains key2

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with the condition that key1 contains key2, here is the example

`df1`

```
name         info
Bill Gates   Microsoft
Steve Jobs   Apple
Elon Musk    Tesla
```

`df2`

```
name        info
Bill        aaa
Kate        bbb
Steve       ccc
```

I'm merging on the key 'name' column,the result I want to get is

`df3`

```
name          info         name     info
Bill Gates    Microsoft    Bill     aaa
Steve Jobs    Apple        Steve    ccc
```

and in my case df1 is relative small with about 600 records, but df2 is pretty large with about 2million records, so efficiency is also a concern, thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a merge, that's something very different.

Comment: Concerning efficiency please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457922/5922920

Answer (score 1):

Rename stuff and merge

```
rename_dict = {'name': 'full', 'info': 'company'}
df1.rename(columns=rename_dict).assign(
    name=lambda d: d.full.str.split().str[0]).merge(df2)

         full    company   name info
0  Bill Gates  Microsoft   Bill  aaa
1  Steve Jobs      Apple  Steve  ccc
```