# Speeding up GROUP BY clause in SQL (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, sql, performance, pandas

I have searched this website thoroughly and have not been able to find a solution that works for me. I code in python, and have very little SQL knowledge. I currently need to create a code to pull data from a SQL database, and organize/summarize it. My code is below: (it has been scrubbed for data security purposes)

```
conn = pc.connect(host=myhost,dbname =mydb, port=myport,user=myuser,password=mypassword)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = ("""CREATE INDEX index ON myTable3 USING btree (name);
    CREATE INDEX index2 ON myTable USING btree (date, state);
    CREATE INDEX index3 ON myTable4 USING btree (currency, type);

    SELECT tp.name AS trading_party_a,
    tp2.name AS trading_party_b,
    ('1970-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone + ((mc.date)::double precision * '00:00:00.001'::interval)) AS val_date,
    mco.currency,
    mco.type AS type,
    mc.state,
    COUNT(*) as call_count,
    SUM(mco.call_amount) as total_call_sum,
    SUM(mco.agreed_amount) as agreed_sum,
    SUM(disputed_amount) as disputed_sum


    FROM myTable mc
    INNER JOIN myTable2 cp ON mc.a_amp_id = cp.amp_id
    INNER JOIN myTable3 tp ON cp.amp_id = tp.amp_id
    INNER JOIN myTable2 cp2 ON mc.b_amp_id = cp2.amp_id
    INNER JOIN myTable3 tp2 ON cp2.amp_id = tp2.amp_id,
    myTable4 mco



    WHERE (((mc.amp_id)::text = (mco.call_amp_id)::text))

    GROUP BY tp.name, tp2.name,
    mc.date, mco.currency, mco.type, mc.state

    LIMIT 1000""")

frame = pdsql.read_sql_query(query,conn)
```

The query takes over 15 minutes to run, even when my limit is set to 5. Before the GROUP BY clause was added, it would run with LIMIT 5000 in under 10 seconds. I was wondering, as I'm aware my SQL is not great, if anybody has any insight on where might be causing delay, as well as any improvements to be made.

EDIT: I do not know how to view the performance of a SQL query, but if someone could inform me on this as well, I could post the performance of the script.

Comment: Can you simplify the joins a little?  Why are you joining back to the same table twice?

Comment: I need to match 2 separate fields from myTable with fields in MyTable2, and then match those two separate values with values from MyTable3. I am at a very beginner level of SQL and do not know if this can be combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to speeding up your workflow, you might be interested in checking out the 3rd part of my answer on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457922/5922920

If you want to keep a SQL-like interface while using a distributed file system you might want to have a look into *Hive*, *Pig* and *Sqoop* in addition to *Hadoop* and *Spark*.

Besides, to trace the performance of your SQL query you can always track the execution time of your code on your client side if appropriate.

For example :

```
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

#Your code here

end_time = timeit.default_timer()

print end_time - start_time
```

Or use tools like those to have a deeper look at what is going on: https://stackify.com/performance-tuning-in-sql-server-find-slow-queries/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im currently looking into some of the software platforms you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

I think the delay is because SQL runs the groupby statement first then it runs everything else. So it is going through your entire large dataset to group everything, then it is going through it again to pull values and do the counts and summations.

Without the groupby, it does not have to parse the entire dataset before it can start generating the results - it jumps right into summing and counting the variables that you desire.