# How do you achieve the SQL aspects in Python?

Tags: python, sql, runtime

I have this prompt (shown below). I think I know how to write it in SQL (also shown below but if it's incorrect please tell me). I want to achieve the same result that SQL does but using Python.

Question - Given a set of data, write a function that will parse the data and 1) find the revenue for the given month 2) find the total capacity of the unreserved offices for the given month.

SQL Guess:

```
SELECT revenue FROM financials WHERE month = "June"
SELECT SUM(capacity) FROM booking WHERE month = "June" and office_reserved IS NULL
```

I don't have actual data for this so I just made up the column names. The first one is straightforward. The second one is I was thinking there would be a database with columns like month - day - office_reserved - capacity (i.e. like 12 people can sit in the room).

Python Guess:

```
arr = []
i = 0
for i < len(financials):
   if financials.month[i] = "June":
      arr.append(financials.revenue[i])
i+=1


arr = []
i = 0
for i < len(booking):
     if booking.month[i] = "June" and office_reserved IS NULL:
          arr.append(booking.capacity[i])
     i+=0
print(sum(arr))
```

This leads me to believe that SQL is computationally faster than Python in instances of finding data. Python is probably faster in instances of large computations or programs. ??

Comment: Python is probably faster when the data fits into memory.  SQL is probably faster for individual look ups and complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

To my extent, you can't interact with a RDBMS using anything else than SQL.
That said there might be Python interfaces for SQL. Not that I know of.

To be able to use other languages such as Python or Javascript (node.js) as a backend solution, you are gonna have to use a noSQL database, meaning mostly a JSON database, which relies on completely different properties, rules and schemes. Now from there you can also make your database ready for large datasets and processing (big data) by opting for a *distributed file system* solution. However, while being way more efficient when dealing with big data, this option might be slower in some specific cases (fast reads, transactions, small datasets,..). More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457922/5922920

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I can think of is pandas. For example, I created a pseudo dataset that you can put into a data frame in order to lookup values. I would do more research on pandas since it is fairly good at working with data similar to this. Here is an example below:

```
Financials = pd.DataFrame([100000, 2000000, 300000, 4000000], columns=['Revenue'], index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'April', 'June'])

print(Financials[Financials['Revenue'] < 400000])
```

And here would be your output:

```
         Revenue
Jan     100000
April   300000
```

You can import data from a .csv or a number of other resources with the pandas library, and perform Boolean selection as it appears you want to do, which is somewhat similar to SQL, but nothing can exactly match the SQL syntax.

A good Library that you may or may not know if is pymysql, which allows you to connect to a MySQL database in Python.

Here is an example from a program that I am using:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

mydb = pymysql.connect(user='sample', passwd='sample_pass', db='medical_app', host='localhost')
cur = mydb.cursor()

select = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM patient_login''')
print(select)
```

As you can see, you can access a database within Python, create a cursor object, and then execute SQL commands. You may or may not know about this already, but I figured it'd be worth noting as well.